# Python No such file or directory: 'file_name.txt\r"

Tags: python, io, path, sungridengine

I'm trying to use a trio of scripts to run a single routine (the routine in the code below) in "batch" mode on a remote SGE-fronted server. For some reason, though, the server is giving me a traceback that says the file I'm trying to read in doesn't exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 102, in <module>
    __main__()
  File "test.py", line 77, in __main__
    with open( str(file_two) ) as open_two:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A00005.txt\r'
```

The file name is indeed "A00005.txt" without the \r bit at the end, and is located in the same directory as the script below--does anyone know why the '\r' is being added to the file path? I'll post the whole code below:

```
import sys, re

#
# Program mainline.
#
def __main__():
    num_runs = 0

    # Parse command line arguments.
    i = 1
    while i < len(sys.argv):
        arg = sys.argv[i]
        if i == 1:
            num_runs = int(arg)
        i += 1

    # In our first execution of the process outlined below, the iteration_number = 0; in the second pass, iteration_number = 1, and so on
    iteration_number = ""
    iteration_number += str(num_runs)

    ##########################################################################################################################################################
    # Using that iteration number, we can divide our routine into all of its constitive components, each of which can be run independently and in parallel
    # Our task, from this point forward, is roughly: read in the "parallel_processing_iteration_schedule" file to determine which two files are to be compared in this iteration
    # Read in those two files, run our matching algorithm, and write out the matching results.
    ##########################################################################################################################################################

    #1) define our parsing functions
    def to_words(text):
        #Break text into a list of words without punctuation
        return re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z']+", text)

    def match(a, b):
        # Make b the longer list.
        if len(a) > len(b):
            a, b = b, a
        # Map each word of b to a list of indices it occupies.
        b2j = {}
        for j, word in enumerate(b):
            b2j.setdefault(word, []).append(j)
        j2len = {}
        nothing = []
        unique = set() # set of all results
        def local_max_at_j(j):
            # maximum match ends with b[j], with length j2len[j]
            length = j2len[j]
            unique.add(" ".join(b[j-length+1: j+1]))
        # during an iteration of the loop, j2len[j] = length of longest
        # match ending with b[j] and the previous word in a
        for word in a:
            # look at all instances of word in b
            j2lenget = j2len.get
            newj2len = {}
            for j in b2j.get(word, nothing):
                newj2len[j] = j2lenget(j-1, 0) + 1
            # which indices have not been extended?  those are
            # (local) maximums
            for j in j2len:
                if j+1 not in newj2len:
                    local_max_at_j(j)
            j2len = newj2len
        # and we may also have local maximums ending at the last word
        for j in j2len:
            local_max_at_j(j)
        return unique

    # 2) Read in metadata file. Because this file is huge (1.4 billion lines long), we'll only read the row in which we're currently interested
    with open("reduced_iteration_schedule.txt") as lookup_table:
        for i, line in enumerate(lookup_table):
            if i == int(iteration_number):

                #the rows in the iteration schedule look like this: iteration_number    text_one    text_two, so let's grab values and delete trailing newline character
                split_line = line.split("\t")
                file_one = split_line[1]
                file_two = split_line[2].replace("\n","")

                with open( str(file_one) ) as open_one:
                    with open( str(file_two) ) as open_two:

                        read_one = open_one.read()
                        read_two = open_two.read()

                        matches = match( to_words(read_one), to_words(read_two) )

            #if we made it to the line beyond our current iteration number, we can stop reading that line, as we've found what we're looking for
            elif i > int(iteration_number):
                break

    # Now we have a list object named "matches" that contains all identified matches between the two texts compared in this iteration.
    # Let's reduce this list so that it contains only those matches that are three words or longer
    reduced_matches = []
    for i in matches:
        if len(i.split()) > 2:
            reduced_matches.append(i)

    # We want to write that to disk, but we can't simply write all matches for all 1.5 billion lookups to the same file, or we'll never be able to open the thing.
    # Let's write the first n iterations to one file (using "append" rather than "write"), then write the next n iterations to a different file

    if int(iteration_number) < 100:
        with open("eebo_string_comparison_1.txt","a") as out:
            out.write( str(file_one) + "\t" + str(file_two) + "\t" + str(reduced_matches) + "\n" )

__main__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
split_line[2].replace("\n","")
```

with:

```
split_line[2].rstrip("\n\r")
```

Carriage returns, `\r`, are part of the line endings used on dos/windows systems and often pop up where they are not wanted.

Comment: I think you gents tied! Thank you both for your answers. The moment I clicked my SO inbox, I heard thunder, so I'm going to wait until the coast is clear before running the script with changes...

Comment: Woohoo! We're in the money! mille grazie!

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a `carriage return` that's left on there. Some platforms use `CR`, `LF` or `CRLF`. It looks like it may be stripping one but not the other.

Your `to_words` function could potentially leave that character there if it was present. Is `\r` persistently there? Or just for that one file?

You could add code to strip all trailing CR and LF chars from the file name tokens, as one option. (You wouldn't want to strip all whitespace, since on some platforms files ending in spaces is allowed.)

Comment: Thanks @Ken; I believe the \r is persistently present, but I'm waiting for a storm to pass before I open the laptop with the details. (I'm writing from a bare-bones XP box from 2002!)